# Why is Chrome rendering Google logo incorrectly?

Tags: google-chrome, rendering

For several months now Chrome has consistently rendered the google logo as follows, top is as Chrome renders, bottom is as IE and piant.net render:

[image]

What's strange is that this is only occurring on the New Tab page,  but the main google page is rendering fine.  The URL is the same for both:

https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png

I'm running google chrome Version 42.0.2311.152 m (on Windows 7 pro x64), which says it's up to date, and only has two disabled extensions, Google Docs 0.9 and Pandora to Spotify Playlist Converter 0.5.0.

I've tried <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, I've cleared browsing data (cached images and files), and it does show up correctly in IE.

What other diagnostic tests should I run to figure out the source of this issue?

Comment: When you view that URL directly in Chrome does it display OK? Incidentally that is the same URL that I see on the New Tab page (in Chrome) and it displays OK for me.  Same version, same OS. (42.0.2311.152 m Win 7 Pro x64)

Comment: @w3d When I go to the URL directly, it shows the corrupted image.  When I go to google.com, it shows the good image (even though it's still the same URL).  When I go to new tab it shows the corrupted image.

Comment: have you tried reinstalling chrome?

Comment: @sehams No, not yet. I'm more interested in why and how this is happening than in fixing it, so re-installing is something I'll do when I've run out of all other options.

Comment: The same image (same URL path) seems to be located on different Google domains. You could trying accessing these, such as https://www.google.co.id/images/srpr/logo11w.png - Don't suppose you've seen corrupt images anywhere else?

Comment: @w3d Interesting! That link is rendered perfectly fine.  The kicker, though, is that I've downloaded the image via chrome and IE, and both downloaded images render fine in chrome. This is getting stranger and stranger... I have not seen similarly corrupt images anywhere else.

Comment: I was going to suggest checking the md5 hash of the downloaded image, but if the downloaded image is displaying OK!? FWIW, the md5 hash of the logo11w.png at google.com that I see is `57e396baedfe1a034590339082b9abce`

Comment: My strong suspicion is badly written malware that is trying to inspect and manipulate Chrome's process space directly.

Comment: It could be that your harddrive has one or more bad sectors, and that the image is partly in that region. As a result, the file pointer to that specific image is pointed to a region with bad blocks, causing the image to not load correctly, in your case with garbage data. To test this, find the image in question on your harddrive, Get a good working copy into the respected folder, then delete the old, and rename the new to old. It should fix the issue.